# How to manage and process objects of a class only created on the heap?

Tags: c++, class, stack, heap-memory

I have an Object class and ObjectManager class that is supposed to hold pointers to Objects created on the heap and is in charge of housekeeping. i.e., (I don't want to have pointers to temporary Objects, for instance when an object is passed to a function by value). I'd like to do some process on the items in the ObjectManager class and later release the memory.

Please consider the following files:

"Object.h" file

```
#pragma once
#include<algorithm>
#include "ObjectManager.h"

class ObjectManager;
class Object{
private:
int value;
static bool heap_flag;

public:

    Object() {
        if (heap_flag) {
            heap_flag = false;
            ObjectManager::vo.push_back(this);
            }
        }

    ~Object() {}

    void* operator new (size_t sz){
        heap_flag = true;
        return malloc(sz);
    }

    void setValue(int v) { value = v; }

};
```

and "ObjectManager.h"

```
#pragma once
#include "Object.h"
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

class Object;
class ObjectManager{

private:
    ObjectManager() {}

public:

static vector <Object*> vo;   // vector that holds pointers to all objects created on heap

static void releaseObjects() {

    size_t index = 0;
        for (auto o : vo){
            // iterate through the vector and delete the object create on heap

            delete o;
            vo[index] = NULL;
            index++;
        }


    }


};
```

finally in the client code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "Object.h"
#include "ObjectManager.h"

using namespace std;

bool Object::heap_flag = false;
vector<Object*> ObjectManager::vo;

void process_Heap_objects (vector<Object*>) {

// ... code to iterate through the elements of a vector and do some process


}

int main() {

Object o; // created on stack
Object* po = new Object(); // created on heap

ObjectManager::vo[0]->setValue(100);

process_Heap_Objects(ObjectManager::vo); 

ObjectManager::releaseObjects();

return 0;
}
```

when I compile this file I get the following warning in  VS2013 -> "warning C4150: deletion of pointer to incomplete type 'Object'; no destructor called
1> Objectmanager.h: see declaration of 'Object'"

the code compiles fine and works as expected though.

two questions:

1- what does the warning mean?

2- is this a good design? is there a better way to achieve this? what are your thoughts?

Comment: You want to have a `virtual` destructor for `Object`: without that, you'll get undefined behaviour when `delete`ing a pointer to an object of derived type. Also, note that you'll need to provide a matching `operator delete()` when you define an `operator new()`.

Comment: good point, I don't intend to derive from this class though.

Comment: The compiler only has a forward declaration of Object, it cannot know whether it has a destructor.  You'll have to define it before releaseObjects().

Comment: Oh, right: you actually call `delete o;` at a place where `Object` isn't defined. That leads to undefined behaviour if `Object` has a non-trivial destructor (i.e., has a destructor or a member which has non-trivial destructor.

Comment: hmmm. can you offer any hint how to fix this?

Comment: Sure: define your `ObjectManager::releaseObject()` function after `Object` was defined. Note the member functions don't have to be defined within the class definition.

Comment: Put releaseObject() in your source file and get it out of the header. Also get `#include "Object.h"` out of the header and put that in the source file.

Comment: Why not put a destroyer method together with the object as pair on the same list or on a parallel list?

Comment: Also, consider making your heap_flag be a static thread_local variable, or you can get weird results if you have a multi-threadded application with both heap and stack instances of your object(s) in different threads.

Comment: thank you all! the warning problem is solved. Do you think this good approach to managing objects on the heap? is this a good practice?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't call a destructor on a forward declared class.

You must put the destructor call in a compilation unit where it can see the declaration of the destructor (e.g. where you #include the Object.h).

Also, stylistic tips:

- On pass by value:

  - If the object is not going to be mutated or copied by the method, pass by const ref `foo (const Object& bar) {}`
  - If the object is going to be mutated but not copied by the method, pass by reference `foo (Object& bar) {}`
  - If the object is going to be copied by the method, pass by value
  - If the method takes possession of the object, pass by pointer
- pragma once is not officially part of the standard, and rarely offers faster compilation in current generation compilers. Most style guides recommended to use include guards:

  ```
  #ifndef SOME_NAME
  #define SOME_NAME
  ... body ...
  #endif
  ```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is you are defining and implementing both `Object` and `ObjectManager` in the header files. This creates a circular dependency because each header file includes the other.

A better approach would be to only have the class definitions in the headers and the bodies of the methods in cpp files.

The warning you're receiving is due to Object not being  defined. Because you have `#pragma once` you aren't seeing the error you should be seeing (the effect of the circular dependency.) This is preventing the ObjectManager from seeing how the Object class is defined.